# On sum over non trivial zeroes of riemann zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

I wanted to know if there is an estimate or any closed form on the following partial sum series

$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{|\alpha_n||(\zeta'(\alpha_n))|}$$

Where "$\alpha_n$" runs over all non-trivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function.

Here $\zeta'(s)$ is the derivative of Riemann zeta function

Assuming all zeroes are of order 1.

Comment: If we merely assume the zeros are of order 1, this gives no lower bound on $\zeta'(\alpha_n)$, so we can't give any upper bound.

Comment: Nothing is known unconditionally, but it is conjectured that $\sum_{|\gamma| \leq T} \frac{1}{|\rho \zeta'(\rho)|} \asymp (\log T)^{5/4}$. See this paper for further discussion: https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024611504014741

Comment: @PeterHumphries thanks for the paper it answered all my queries, I was looking for this only.